# Python pyqt error when using QTextEdit.find(): unexpected type 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, pyqt4

Trying to use the builtin 'find' function of the QTextEdit widget but when I try to pass the text from a QLineEdit widget, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SVN\Gocator\Trunk\Gocator\GoPy\Scripts\testfind.pyw", line 52, in on_find_button_clicked
    self.fileEdit.find(self.findLine.text)
TypeError: QTextEdit.find(str, QTextDocument.FindFlags options=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

I've reviewed the documentation for the QTextEdit class and there's not much to it but I can't figure out why it's giving me the error. What's interesting is if I replace the reference to the QLineEdit text property with a string literal (e.g. "What") in the find() call (line 52: **self.fileEdit.find(self.findLine.text**)), it will work.

My test code is pretty straight forward so I think it's just something I'm not seeing right in front of my eyes. Does anyone see where I went wrong or even get the same issue? Here's my test script (I only have Qt4 installed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Needs Qt5 (recommended) or Qt4

# PyQt5: run pip3 install pyqt5
# PyQt4: from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

import shelve
import sys

sys.path.append('../GoPy')
sys.path.append('../../GoPy')

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class ControlEngine:
    def __init__(self):

        self.shelf = shelve.open("ui_control.shelf")

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.engine = ControlEngine()
        self.create_ui()

    def create_ui(self):
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        # View group

        viewGroup = QGroupBox("File View")
        viewLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.fileEdit = QTextEdit("Today at Safeway, here's what we have for you.")
        self.fileEdit.setFont(QFont("Courier New", 10))
        viewLayout.addWidget(self.fileEdit)

        self.findButton = QPushButton("Find Next Word")
        self.findButton.clicked.connect(self.on_find_button_clicked)
        self.findLine = QLineEdit("What")
        viewLayout.addWidget(self.findLine)
        viewLayout.addWidget(self.findButton)

        viewGroup.setLayout(viewLayout)
        mainLayout.addWidget(viewGroup)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.fileEdit.moveCursor(1)

    @pyqtSlot(int, int)

    def on_find_button_clicked(self):
        self.fileEdit.find(self.findLine.text)

class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, argv):
        QApplication.__init__(self, argv)

    def start(self):
        mainWindow = MainWindow()
        self.mainWindow = mainWindow
        mainWindow.resize(300, 300)
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle("Test Find")
        mainWindow.show()

        return self.exec_()

def main():
    app = App(sys.argv)    
    sys.exit(app.start())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
    self.fileEdit.find(self.findLine.text)
```

to

```
    self.fileEdit.find(self.findLine.text())
```

because its a function not a property :)

Comment: just removed my answer since you were first ;)

Comment: Arrghhh!! I hate it when I do that..."sigh". Thank you, thank you.

Comment: Happens to everyone :) Could you please accept the answer? Thanks!